# Good extensions for WinDBG?

Tags: .net, debugging, windbg

Does anyone have any good extensions for WinDBG? Specifically managed code? I obviously use SOS, and I've heard/dabbled with a few others as necessary in the past, but never saved them (d'oh!).

I don't really have any good collection of extensions in my toolbox and would like some recommendations!

Answer (score 9):

I've been working on a WinDBG extension for .NET debugging recently called SPT.  I blogged about it [here](http://www.steveniemitz.com/Blog/post/SPT-A-WinDBG-extension-for-debugging-NET-applications.aspx) and have since release the [source code](https://github.com/steveniemitz/SDbgExt2) on github.

It has extensions for a lot of common debugging tasks in .NET, such as dumping all the entries in a dictionary/hashtable, viewing all active SQL connections in a process, or viewing the target method of a delegate, to name a few.

There's also SOSEX, available [here](http://www.stevestechspot.com/SOSEXV40NowAvailable.aspx), which has some great features as well, like a recursive !do and some great tools for examining the managed heaps.

Answer (score 6):

psscor2 and [psscor4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a06a0fea-a4d4-434e-a527-d6afa2e552dd) (for .NET 4) have the same commands as SOS but with some useful features such as showing deltas for `!dumpheap` as well as a couple of additional commands.

Answer (score 3):

The Managed-code Debugging Extension [MEX](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=53304).

Provide enhanced versions of the original SOS/PSSCOR commands and some additional stuff. All properly augmented with DML (so you can click your way around, if you like).

You can even decompile managed "binaries" to C#-like syntax. It has special helpers to deal with Powershell debugging, etc.

Additionally, it has many commands to work with native data structures. And some kernel-mode commands.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft just released this previously internal only plugin as open source, [netext](https://netext.codeplex.com). It apparently has some SQL like querying features of the .NET stack, and comands just for HTTP and WCF.